# Are speed camera POIs database or location suitable question for this site?

Tags: discussion, questions

I know some people (me included) interested by sharing speed camera poi's or database and asking question regarding this topic.

Is that subject considered as a proper topic or it is borderline or totally discouraged?

I asked because in some countries these POI's (only concerning speed camera) are forbidden, but in my opinion it is not (yet) forbidden to talk about the subject.

Comment: It is still geographic data, go ahead and ask your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not able to say whether this "subject [is] considered as a proper topic or it is borderline or totally discouraged" because it will depend on the Questions asked.

Furthermore, your Meta Question does not include any examples that I can use to form and provide an opinion on.

I recommend that you post a Question or two over on Main and the community will no doubt provide quick feedback on whether such Questions appear on/off topic for this site.